# What is the impact on hadoop cluster when Secondary Namenode fails

Tags: hadoop

What happens to hadoop cluster when `Secondary NameNode` fails.

Hadoop cluster is said to be a single point of failure as all medata is stored by NameNode. What about Secondary NameNode, if secondary namenode fails, will Cluster fail or keep running.

Comment: [Humorous take on SNN concept](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEqQMLSXQlY).  No offense intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondary name node is little bit confusing name. Hadoop Cluster will run when it crashes. You can run Hadoop claster even without it and it is not used for high availability. I am talking about Hadoop versions  <2.
More info: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#What_is_the_purpose_of_the_secondary_name-node.3F